# how do i create this association

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have the following 2 sql server tables

```
Products
locationCode (PK), prodId (PK), productName
---------------------------------
AUG, 1, Widget
ATL, 1, Widget

Categories
prodId (PK) catId (PK), catName
----------------------------------
1, 1, WidgetsCategory
1, 1, WidgetsCategory
```

What would I need to do to create an association where a single product can have many categories given the required fields and (PK) Primary keys?

Comment: Can multiple products belong to the same category? In other words, is it 1 to N or M to N relationship between products and categories?

Comment: what makes your product unique, does the location code matter?  If not use the prodID and a reference to the catID.

Comment: IN SQL Server you can only have 1 Primary Key per table and each Primary Key must be unique. So can you clarify which fields should be the PK's?

Comment: The data you've posed for the `Categories` table has duplicate rows i.e. would violate the PK! :)

Comment: At first I thought `Products` must have a composite key `(locationCode, prodId)` but only `prodId` is referenced in `Categories` which suggests there is a key on `prodId` alone. Then there's those duplicate rows in `Categories`... I think you need to make your (proposed?) schema a little clearer. Posting SQL DDL (`CREATE TABLE Categories...`) and sample data (`INSERT INTO Categories...`) makes it a lot easier on the person answering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one more table that relates products to categories.
This table should contain the key of products and a foreign key (category id).

In your original question you don't mention whether the location code matters or not.  You also don't mention if this is a 1-N or M-N type relationship.
Provide a bit more detail to get additional help.

When you normalize your tables you ensure every table has fields related with only itself (unless of course you are creating that relationship and you store the keys to make that relationship).

Your categories table should only include categories, and should not have anything to do with a product.  Once you establish a Category entity, you then relate that category to another product, via another table.

Comment: +1 : Agreed, the Category table shouldn't have product id's in it.  Instead each entry in Category should be unique, and then have a seperate table mapping Product:Category.